# Trying to Query on Login and based on email and password return First Name

Tags: python, django

I a have a SQLite Database with:
first_name   email     password
Andrew       t@t.com   abcde

I am using this to check if there is a matching email and password:

```
if User.userManager.filter(email = postData['email'], password = 
postData['password']):
            name = User.userManager.filter(email = postData['email'], password = postData['password'])
            print name.get('first_name')
            return "success"
```

When I try to print first_name from the query i did above I get error 'too many values to unpack'

Comment: you did not have encrypted password of user or passing encrpted password from POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because get() method expecting for keyword arguments:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get

The QuerySet returned by `filter()` method could contain more than one entry:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#filter
, so you should specify expected value for the requested field.

One of the ways to access this value is:

```
print name.get(first_name='Andrew').first_name
```

On the other hand, you could limit your filter query:

```
User.userManager.filter(email = postData['email'], password = postData['password'])[:1]
```

Or just use `get()` method straightway and access field value directly:

```
user = User.userManager.get(email = postData['email'], password = postData['password'])
print user.first_name
```